# Эмуляция ввода в консоль.

Tags: php, консоль, linux

Цель - создать FTP пользователя средствами php exec() - рут у скрипта уже есть.

```
useradd user1 -p user1 -d /home/user1
```

Пользователь отлично создаётся, каталог на месте, но... vsftpd не видит его(пользователя). Никак.
Видит при условии, если создавать через adduser.

```
adduser user1
```

После чего следует ввод пароля два раза и остальные данные. Но в одну строку(читай: так, что бы можно было сделать через exec()) такой командой нельзя.

Единственное, что приходит в голову - сделать эмуляцию ввода пароля.
Менять на proftpd не советуйте.

Так вот, есть ли какие-то способы эмулировать ввод в консоль текста средствами bash или, на крайний случай, php?

Answer (score 1):

программа `useradd` не устанавливает пароль для вновь созданного пользователя. поэтому под этим именем и невозможно «залогиниться» — ни по протоколу *ftp*, ни как-либо ещё.

задать/изменить пользователю(-ям) пароль(-и) не-интерактивно можно, например, с помощью программы [`chpasswd`](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=chpasswd&category=8&russian=0):

```
$ echo пользователь:пароль | chpasswd
```